# How to add existing django project to Aptana Studio 3 without modifying files?

Tags: python, django, aptana-studio

I have created a new Django project using `django-admin startproject mysite` on `C:\tuts\` The initial file structure is as shown in the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project) where the root folder of the project contains only one file `manage.py` and one folder `mysite`.

When I tried to create a Django project in Aptana studio 3 as follows:

```
File -> New -> Project... -> PyDev -> PyDev Django Project
```

Then after have I set Project contents to the folder `C:\tuts\mysite`, I had got extra files in the original project root directory.

So I need a way by which the original file structure does not be changed when I add this project to Aptana Studio 3. I'm new to Django and Python.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?